# Derivation of the 4 types of real-valued linear-phase FIR filters

Tags: filters, finite-impulse-response, reference-request, linear-phase

Is there any resource or literature where I can find derivations/proofs for all four linear phase filter types starting from an arbitrary real valued impulse response? I looked at some of the literature such as [Introduction to Digital Filters](https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/filters/) but couldn't find anything concrete.

Comment: T. W. Parks and C. S. Burrus, Digital Filter Design,
New York: John Wiley and Sons, Inc., June 1987

Comment: Should be in any textbook on digital signal processing. But what do you mean by "starting from an arbitrary real valued impulse response"?

Comment: (1/2) Here is what I mean by an arbitrary real impulse response:
Starting with $h[n]$ we can get $H(e^{j\omega})$ by taking its DTFT:

$$H(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}h[n] e^{-j\omega n}$$

Now, Linear-phase filters have a symmetric impulse response, e.g.,
$$ h(n) = h(N-1-n), \quad n=0,1,2,\ldots,N-1.$$

Comment: (2/2) The symmetric-impulse-response constraint means that linear-phase filters must be FIR filters, because a causal recursive filter cannot have a symmetric impulse response. But it also means other things for the frequency response which we can realise by taking advantage of that symmetry. Now where can I find the complete proof for all four cases starting with these steps?

Comment: @MattL. what I am saying is that the results can be found in many of the DSP books. But I cannot seem to find a step by step proof for the results.

Comment: @CaporalFourrier: Have you checked Oppenheim's Discrete Time Signal Processing? I'm pretty sure it's in there. Also, take a look at [this document](https://eeweb.engineering.nyu.edu/iselesni/EL713/zoom/linphase.pdf). Maybe you can then reformulate your question to be a bit more specific.

Comment: @MattL. I am sorry I couldn't find such a proof in Oppenheim's Discrete Time Signal Processing (3rd Ed.) either. And as for the document you provided, I already had it. Now as you can see the author of the document doesn't exactly prove each type of filter from scratch but rather using examples of small order frequency responses and then just writing the general form for each case.

Comment: @CaporalFourrier: In Oppenheim's book, have you read Section 5.7 "Linear Systems with Generalized Linear Phase"? Please let us know which questions remain that are not covered in that section.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to prove, but perhaps the discussion at the following web page would be of interest to you:
https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/808.php

Comment: @MattL. Yes, this section is more appropriate for what I was looking for. Thanks, a lot!